# Prove that $X$ and $Y$ follow a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Let two random variables $X$ e $Y$ with the following joint distribution function:
$$
F(x,y)=\Phi(x)\Phi(y)[1+\alpha(1-\Phi(x))(1-\Phi(y))]
$$
with $|\alpha|\leq 1$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ the distribution function of a standard normal distribution. Prove that the marginal distributions corresponding to $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal.

I'm having some problems proving this statement. I only have to prove it for $X$ because for $Y$, the procedure is the same.

To prove for $X$, I'm using the fact that $f_{X}(x)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)dy$ and that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial x \partial y}(x,y)$.

The problem with this approach is that I obtain a very long expression and when I try to integrate, I obtain terms like $\displaystyle\int\Phi(y)f(y)dy$ that i do not know how to resolve. I'm not sure if I have some errors calculating $f_{X,Y}$ or if this is the incorrect approach to prove this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$F(x,y):=P(X\le x, Y\le y),\tag{*}$$ a quick way to obtain the marginal distribution for $X$ is to let $y\to\infty$ in (*); the RHS will then converge to $P(X\le x)$.

Comment: But if I do $y\to\infty$, then $\Phi(y)\to 0$, I think, So $F(x,y)\to 0$.

Comment: $\Phi(y)\to 1$ when $y\to\infty$.

Comment: Agh, I confused with the density function. What does RHS mean?

Comment: RHS means 'right hand side'.